# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel

I am getting this error randomly in my PHP project. I am using Laravel framework. I googled around a bit and found that is an issue occurring due to PDO. I tried to log the query I am trying to run just before the error occurs and when I copy and run the same query through MySQL, it runs absolutely fine. Following is the code snippet:

```
foreach($batches as $batch){
        $query_post = "INSERT INTO posts (`fb_post_id`, `page_id`, `from_user_id`,`to_user_id`, ".
                        "`object_id`, `from`,`to`, `message`, `picture`,`link`, `icon`, `type`,`name`, ".
                        "`status_type`, `privacy`,`caption`, `description`,`story`, `actions`, `created_time`, ".
                        "`comment_count`,`like_count`, `created_at`) VALUES ";
        $query = '';
        foreach($batch as $row){
            $comma_separated = implode("','", $row);
            $query .= "('".$comma_separated."'),";
        }
        $query_post .= $query;
        $query_post= substr($query_post, 0, -1);
        $query_post= utf8_encode($query_post);
        Log::write('info', ' POST QUERY : '.$query_post);
        DB::query($query_post);
    }
```

After a few runs in the loop, I get the error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 in laravel/database/connection.php line 293.
It would be a great help if someone could give me a sound solution for it.

P.S.: A few runs means a random number and it does not occur at some specific point. My PHP version is 5.3.10 and I have got the same error on 5.4.4 as well.

Comment: According to [this](http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=596), if using Larevel 3.0 you should use `DB::statement` instead of `DB::query`

Comment: mysql error 2053: "attempt to read a row while there is no result set associated with the statement". You're using the wrong query call to run your insert.

Comment: Why not use their ORM instead?  Probably less errors.

Comment: Also, what if $comma_separated has a quote in it?  `don't` or `can't` would throw it off if it is in the message or whatever.

Comment: @TimWithers : I just forgot to mention it, but all the strings in $batches have been properly escaped and encoded using mysql_real_escape_string() and base64_encode() functions.

Comment: @cillosis : I also had a look into the link previously, but DB::statement did not help. Instead, changing it resulted in no insertions taking place at all. So, I had to scrap off the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

`DB::statement()` instead of `DB::query()`

Hope it help you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually what laravel suggests is using the correct statement for your operation

```
DB::delete()
DB::update()
DB::insert()
DB::select()
```

the reason is because statement() does not return the affected rows response
which update, insert and delete does

and of course select returns the selected results collection, this will always allow you to log and interperet your code better

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
foreach($batches as $batch){
    $query_post = "INSERT INTO posts (`fb_post_id`, `page_id`, `from_user_id`,`to_user_id`, ".
                    "`object_id`, `from`,`to`, `message`, `picture`,`link`, `icon`, `type`,`name`, ".
                    "`status_type`, `privacy`,`caption`, `description`,`story`, `actions`, `created_time`, ".
                    "`comment_count`,`like_count`, `created_at`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Log::write('info', ' POST QUERY : '.$query_post);
    DB::query($query_post,$batch);
}
```

Using parameter-ized queries might be better and fix the issue... maybe.  Don't really know the data you are passing into it.

Answer (score -1):

Use excute ,not  query.
select returns the selected results collection, this will always allow you to log and interperet your code better

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.